# What happened to the chorddiag package in R?

Tags: chord-diagram

While working in Rstudio, I cannot seem to find the chorddiag package.   Does it still exist?  I've restarted Rstudio in 3.3, 3.5, and 4.0 versions of R, and each seem unable to find the package using either devtools::install_github("mattflor/chorddiag") or the install.package tools.  Moreover, after installing devtools, it cannot be found.  I'm still learning R, so I'm probably doing something wrong.  But I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Restating my question, there are actually two issues:
1. This error message: package ‘chordDiag’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1) ( I tried it again with other versions, and 
2. > devtools::install_github("mattflor/chorddiag", build_vignettes = TRUE), yields this error.
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rlang’

Comment: I just tried circlize, and it is not a good comparison.  Yes, I certainly could not have created that myself with my current skills, and yes, it is a chord diagram.  But it is not interactive.  This page is still on the web, but as of yet seems unapplicable.  https://datascience-enthusiast.com/R/Interactive_chord_diagrams_R.html

Comment: Greetings to all.  I have found a workaround.  I've just gone to the raw code and I'm making individual changes on my own.  Otherwise, I would be stuck.  I'm leaving the embedded copyright claims in place.  I'm using the graphic internally.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to complete the install and load the library doing the following:

```
install.packages("devtools")

devtools::install_github("mattflor/chorddiag", build_vignettes = TRUE)

library(chorddiag)
```

I'm using R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) on Windows 10 via Rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have an answer.  So I've gone to the raw html and css to adjust the diagram.  It's painstaking work, but worth the effort.  I'm leaving copyright claims in place within the code.